# Is it typical to have UTF8 octets double-encoded as \uFF80-\uFFFF range?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, utf-8, google-chrome-devtools

I have been playing with Google Chrome DevTools protocol, and I have encountered strange outputs for the pages with Unicode characters in their title.

I have a page titled `unicode - Google 検索`. DevTools API reports this as a Target with title `"unicode - Google \uFFE6\uFFA4\uFF9C\uFFE7\uFFB4\uFFA2"`, as received in JSON. However, codepoints provided by the API are invalid: they correspond to `unicode - Google ￦ﾤﾜ￧ﾴﾢ`, not the original title.

I had double checked — this is not a problem of my implementation, because DevTools inspector shows the same mojibake:

[image: Partial screenshot of Devtools showing the mojibake in <code>title</code> field]

Now, if we take lower 8 bits from each codepoint in the string, and threat them as they were an UTF-8 string: `"unicode - Google \xE6\xA4\x9C\xE7\xB4\xA2"`, this would decode into `unicode - Google 検索`, as originally expected.

This looks way too complicated to be just an encoding bug, and given that web pages with Unicode in titles are way too common in the web, this should have been noticed and fixed long ago.

So, this has to be a feature somehow. Is this some kind of UTF-8 embedding?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Chrome. Buggy behavior can look complicated, indeed.

Comment: As noted, `検索` is encoded in UTF-8 as bytes `E6 A4 9C E7 B4 A2`. All of those bytes have the high bit set to 1. The `FF` is an indication that the bytes are been sign-extended to 16-bit values. So, it sounds like the original Unicode title is being UTF-8 encoded, and then the bytes are being converted as-is into 16-bit string characters that are then interpreted as UTF-16, instead of the UTF-8 being decoded and converted to UTF-16 properly.